# NameError: global name 'NAME' is not defined <SOLVED>

Tags: ros, navigation, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people! :)  i am listening GPS's data and i want use them in another part of my code, for do Path Planing, but when I try to use them, it give me back this error

I defined variable global (global Lon, Lat) in many places like inside of def listener(), def backlatitud(): and def backlongitud() and it give back the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ceres_pkg/src/Controlador.py", line 25, in <module>
    listener()
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ceres_pkg/src/Controlador.py", line 20, in listener
    print Lat
NameError: global name 'Lat' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
global Lon, Lat

def backlatitud(data1):
    Lat = float(data1.data)
    #rospy.loginfo('Latitud %s', data1.data)
    return;

def backlongitud(data):
    Lon = float(data.data)
    #rospy.loginfo('longitud %s', Lon)
    return;

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/latitud", String, backlatitud)
    rospy.Subscriber("/longitud", String, backlongitud)
    print Lat
    print Lon
    rospy.spin()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245663/nameerror:-global-name-%27name%27-is-not-defined-%3Csolved%3E/) by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
Please format code & console copy/pastes using the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) in the future. That makes things much easier to read. Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
Also: how is this related to [NameError: global name 'NAME' is not defined](http://answers.ros.org/question/245537)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `listener()` function, `Lat` and `Lon` are being accessed prior to any initialisation. If you remove the two `print` statements before `rospy.spin()`, your code should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on 2016-10-13**:
Yes, that work fine, but I need work with this variables (Lat and Lon) in another function, how do I call them?

for example
def function():
LatNew = 2 * Lat
LonNew = 2 * Lon
Print LatNew
Print LonNew

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-14**:
I'd recommend you use a class, instead of a flat file with a set of free functions. That would work-around all the issues you are having.

**Comment by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on 2016-10-18**:
thanks @gvdhoom that's true, I did include a class, look at my final code
[C:\fakepath\Captura.JPG](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14768482916494731.jpg)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-19**:
Please don't use screenshots to post what is essentially text.